# errro while creating apk through apktool d2j-dex2jar

Tags: java, android, decompiling, apktool

Getting following error while recompiling apktool generated code:

```
d2j-dex2jar b base
```

**Error:**

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: b
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Unknown Source)
>           at com.googlecode.d2j.reader.zip.ZipUtil.readDex(ZipUtil.java:57)
>           at com.googlecode.d2j.reader.zip.ZipUtil.readDex(ZipUtil.java:53)
>           at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.doCommandLine(Dex2jarCmd.java
>   :104)
>           at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.BaseCmd.doMain(BaseCmd.java:288)
>           at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.main(Dex2jarCmd.java:32)

Comment: There is no option -b. Read the man from `d2j-dex2jar --help`.

Comment: @zed I have used this command with 'b' for creating other apk files

Comment: This is for apktool not dex2jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use incorrect flag. Thus error says: i do not understand you : 'b'  file doesn't exist. Read help more carefully.

**EDIT**

> d2j-dex2jar --help
>
> d2j-dex2jar -- convert dex to jar
>
> usage: d2j-dex2jar [options]  [file1 ... fileN]
>
> options:
>
> -d,--debug-info              translate debug info
>
> -e,--exception-file    detail exception file, default is
>   $current_dir/[file-name]-error.zip
>
> -f,--force                   force overwrite
>
> -h,--help                    Print this help message
>
> -n,--not-handle-exception    not handle any exception throwed by
>   dex2jar
>
> -o,--output    output .jar file, default is
>   $current_dir/[file-na
>                                 me]-dex2jar.jar
>
> -os,--optmize-synchronized   optmize-synchronized
>
> -p,--print-ir                print ir to Syste.out
>
> -r,--reuse-reg               reuse regiter while generate java .class
>   file
>
> -s                           same with --topological-sort/-ts
>
> -ts,--topological-sort       sort block by topological, that will
>   generate more
>                                  readable code
>
> -v,--verbose                 show progress
>
> version: reader-1.15, translator-0.0.9.15, ir-1.12

to assemble and disassmble , please, read manual:

https://sourceforge.net/p/dex2jar/wiki/ModifyApkWithDexTool/

```
# build jar

d2j-jasmin2jar.sh -f  -o test_apk_jasmin.jar  test_apk_jasmin/ 

# verify jar

d2j-asm-verify.sh test_apk_jasmin.jar

# convert to dex

d2j-jar2dex.sh  -f -o classes.dex test_apk_jasmin.jar

# make a copy

cp test_apk-debug.apk test_apk-debug-toast.apk

# replace classes.dex in test_apk-debug-toast.apk

zip -r test_apk-debug-toast.apk classes.dex

# sign the apk

d2j-apk-sign.sh -f -o test_apk-debug-toast-signed.apk test_apk-debug-toast.apk
```

Comment: I have used this command with 'b' for creating other apk files, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZzGUNm_yX0

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam , lol . this is not possilble. read my updated answer . no flag `b`

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam , lol . in your link wrote you have to use `apktools` instead of `d2j-dex2jar`